# How to grep array of arrays

Tags: perl

```
@array1 = ('20020701', 'Sending Mail in Perl', 'Philip Yuson');
@array2 = ('20020601', 'Manipulating Dates in Perl', 'Philip Yuson');
@array3 = ('20020501', 'GUI Application for CVS', 'Philip Yuson');

@main = (\@array1, \@array2, \@array3);
use Data::Dumper ;
print Dumper \@main ;
print grep { $_ =~ /Manipulating Dates in Perl/} @main ;
```

How to make the grep working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print grep { $_->[1] =~ /Manipulating Dates in Perl/} @main ;
```

If you are just going for flat string comparison, you should use this instead:

```
print grep { $_->[1] eq 'Manipulating Dates in Perl'} @main ;
```

The regular expression will match any string that *contains* the string "Manipulating Dates in Perl".

To explain, `$_` will contain an array reference.  `$_->[1]` will dereference the array and obtain the element at index 1.

Comment: prints the arrayref, probably not what is actually wanted (though what *is* wanted is a mystery)

Comment: @ysth: Good point.  Yes, this will print the arrayref, but it will grep and print the *correct* arrayref at least.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could stringify the inner array before you match a pattern:

```
@result = grep { "@$_" =~ /Manipulating Dates in Perl/ } @main;
```

This could also be a job for the [smart match operator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsyn#Smart_matching_in_detail):

```
@result = grep { $_ ~~ /Manipulating Dates in Perl/} @main;
```

This matches any array reference in `@main` that has at least one element that matches the given regular expression.

In both cases the output is a list of array references, which might not be what you want to display.

Comment: I would have linked to [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail "Smart matching in detail")

Answer (score 0):

Dereference them with map:

```
grep { $_ =~ /please match/ } map { @{$_} } @arrays
```

Honestly it looks like you'd rather have hash references:

```
my @docs = ( 
    {id => '20020701', "title" => 'Sending Mail in Perl',  "author" =. 'Philip Yuson'},
    {id => '20020601', "title" => 'Manipulating Dates in Perl', "author" => 'Philip Yuson'}
);

foreach (grep { $_->{"title"} =~ /Manipulating Dates/ } @docs) {
    print "Got match " . $_->{"id"} . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## hope this helps...

use feature 'say';

```
my @fruit      = ('apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'bananas', 'grapes');
my @dry_goods  = ('corn meal', 'sugar', 'flour', 'corn flakes');
my @sea_food   = ('flounder', 'lobster', 'baked clams');
my @drinks     = ('apple juice', 'milk', 'coke');

my @groceries  = (\@fruit, \@dry_goods, \@sea_food, \@drinks);

foreach (  map { grep {/apple/} @{$_}  }  @groceries ) { say $_ };
```